# Error in H2 Database: "Domain 'int' not found"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb, h2

```
@Column(name = "trust", length = 1, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int")
private Boolean trust;
```

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Domain "int" not found;

I believe the issue is with the data type specification. How should I correctly define these columns in H2(version: 2.1.214) for intregation test? I'm also using MariaDB, so any suggestions on compatibility between the two databases would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

H2 data types: https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html
MariaDB data types: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/data-types/

Since H2 does not support "int" type, use "integer" (equivalent to "int" in MariaDB) instead.
Moreover, actual use of the column is Boolean, so it's best to define the column as the same type.